# How to use third-party typescript plugins in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I am new to angular2 but quite mature with javascript development. I used many jQuery plugins in my previous projects. I want to use them all in my new angular2 project as well.

Things which I already know:

1. **I have to use typescript definitions files to use them.**

But what I want to know is

1. **Where to place them in angular2 project.**
2. **Should I use npm to download them, so that they got placed into node_modules
   folder.**
3. **Should I manually copy them in typings folder.**

I tried with point 2 but was not able to take it's reference. Can any one tell me that How can I import third-party typescript plugins and import them in my angular2 components. What is best practice?

Secondly, what is the use of typings folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do the thing. However the modern way is using types from the `node_modules` folder.

In order to do that (if the library itself does not provide the types like Angular does) you need to install the typescript definition files:

```
npm install @types/mylibrarytoimport --save-dev
```

This will take the type definitions from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped. Now the interesting part: how to use it in your project. According to the [docs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html) you don't need to do anything else: it just works.

Before this way became possible there was a `typings` library which tried to fix the problem until they realised they implement a second `npm`, so they just moved to the existing one. Luckily NPM added support of scoped packages which made it possible.

Before `typings` there was no real way to get the type definitions automatically, so everybody was forced to download and track the changes manually.